# How to fix the position of the tableFooterView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` where the user taps an 'Edit' button (already in the `tableHeaderView`) and once they're in editing mode, the `tableFooterView` with a 'Delete' button.

My issue is that the footer scrolls with the table. Is there any way I can make the position fixed (or possibly a different way of doing this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two `UIView`s, and put the `UITableView` in the upper one:

```
+-------------------+
|  +-------------+  |
|  |             |  |
|  |             |  |
|  |    Table    |  |
|  |             |  |
|  |             |  |
|  |             |  |
|  +-------------+  |
|   regular view    |
+-------------------+
|      footer       |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Quick question: Am I adding the regular and footer view the `self.view` of the `UITableViewController` and then adding `self.tableView` to the regular view (Having problems with this part)?